# Button column on CGridView with CSqlDataProvider as provider?

Tags: gridview, yii, dataprovider, cbuttoncolumn

I'm using CSqlDataProvider to provide data for CGridView. It all runs fine until I want to add CButtonColumn column. It resultsl in error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

and in the stack there

```
echo $this->displayExtendedSummary && !empty($this->extendedSummary['columns']) 
        ? $this->parseColumnValue($column, $row) : $column->renderDataCell($row);
```

at file:

```
    c:\...\yii\framework\zii\widgets\grid\CButtonColumn.php(316)
```

Any ideas how to deal with that?

EDIT:
Provider:

```
$provider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
        'totalItemCount' => $countRes,
        'db' => $this->db,
        'keyField' => 'idCall',
        'params' => $params,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 25,
        ),
        'sort' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'idCall, idTime',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

In view:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
'id'=>'call-history-grid',
'type' => 'striped condensed',
'template' => '{pager}{items}{summary}',
'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'font-size: 0.75em'),
'dataProvider'=>$model->getInviteCallList(),
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header' => '#',
        'value' => '$data["idCall"]',
        'visible' => 'Yii::app()->user->superuser',
    ),
    array(
        'header' => 'Data',
        'value' => '$data["callDateTime"]',
    ),
                    array(
        'class'=>'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn',
    ),
```

I use here bootstrap gridview but if I switch to regular CGridView - problem is the same.

Comment: Show us your gridview columns code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, unlike `CActiveDataProvider`, `CSqlDataProvider` doesn't have all the needed information to support default `CButtonColumn` buttons.

`CActiveDataProvider` will provide object, but `CSqlDataProvider` will provide array, and `CButtonColumn` works with objects, that's why you get "*Trying to get property of non-object*" error message...

You should define buttons url, e.g. :

```
array(
  'class'=>'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn',
  'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/mycontroller/view", array("id"=>$data["idCall"]))',
  'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/mycontroller/update", array("id"=>$data["idCall"]))',
  'deleteButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/mycontroller/delete", array("id"=>$data["idCall"]))',
),
```

Comment: It is not enough unfortunately. It still calls the `$data->primaryKey` after doing `extract($data)`.

Comment: `extract($data)` ?? where do you see this ? please update your question with your current code.

Comment: My bad. Your solution is ok. I made one mistake in url. BTW - `extract($data)` is in the CComponent.php (in yii framework). After extracting data there is `eval` function wich was causing the problems. Your solution is totally ok. Thank you!